# How can i program pointers to struct or class variables in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, pointer-to-member

In my code i am trying to have the members of an int pointer-array point to the members of the int array in my struct Bucket. The problem i get is that when running the program, i can copy the first 3 members, but as i try to copy the 4th, i get a runtime error. Why is this? Am I setting the pointers right? What should I do differently?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    struct Bucket 
    {
         int values[10];
         Bucket()
         {
            n=0; 
            t=0;
         }
    };

    int* Ordnung[10];
    Bucket Neuerbucket;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        Neuerbucket.values[i]=i;

    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        std::cout<< Neuerbucket.values[i];

    std:: cout<< '\n';
    int* array[10];

    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        *array[j]=(Neuerbucket.values[j]);
        std:: cout<<*array[j];
    }
    std:: cout << "TROLOL"; 

    return 1;
}
```

NOTE: This is not a program that should do anything, it is just for the better understanding of pointers and classes/structs. The knowledge I hope to get through your answers will hopefully help me to program my data structure program.
Thanks in advance, you're the best, J.K. :)

Comment: What is `n` and `t` in `Bucket`? Couldn't you post code correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
*array[j]=(Neuerbucket.values[j]);
```

Should probably be:

```
array[j]=&Neuerbucket.values[j];
```

Otherwise you're putting int values from `Neuerbucket` wherever the uninitialized pointers of `array` point.